# How to get a string from another string by regular express?

Tags: php, curl

I want to get the `js` file by PHP CURL, then using regular express to get the value of `var pluses`, so the output should be `/\+/g`. Could someone advise what wrong with my code?

Thanks

Here is what I have tried, but no luck:

```
$url = 'http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.3/jquery.cookie.js';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

preg_match('/^var\spluses\s=\s/', $output, $match);
print_r($match);
```

Live code: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/x4w-cn5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your match, you need to select it. try

```
preg_match('/var\spluses\s=\s(.*);/', $output, $match);
```

The value assigned to pluses should be in `$match[1]`.

The `^` at the beginning of your regex is the start of line delimiter, which limited the selection to a line starting with the characters `var`, not considering the indentation.

```
preg_match('/^\s*var\spluses\s=\s(.*);/', $output, $match);
```

This regex would limit to a line with any (`*`) whitespaces before the `var` keyword.

Comment: @CharlesYeung it is the start of line `^` that should not be there.